# Can't write Tensorflow scalar summary to event log

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, filewriter, summary, scalar

i'm trying to learn how to write tensorflow code on my own, but i'm stuck with this very basic issue:
During learning steps i can't write any scalar summary to the event file, which is needed for Tensorboard. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
WORKDIR = "/content/log"

x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)

y_pred = linear_model(x)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.name_scope("TRAIN"):
  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
  train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(WORKDIR + "/tmp/5", graph=sess.graph)

sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
  _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
  if i % 50 == 0:
    writer.add_summary(summary=loss_value, global_step=i)
    print(str(i)+" step: "+str(loss_value))
    writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

the error i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-732ee0fb1e1c> in <module>()
     27   _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
     28   if i % 50 == 0:
---> 29     writer.add_summary(summary=loss_value, global_step=i)
     30     print(str(i)+" step: "+str(loss_value))
     31     writer.flush()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py in add_summary(self, 
 summary, global_step)
    123     # to save space - we just store the metadata on the first value 
with a
    124     # specific tag.
--> 125     for value in summary.value:
    126       if not value.metadata:
    127         continue

AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Pls help me correct my code, because i have read a lot of issues around the topic but never encountered this specific problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scalar summary or any summaries in general are collected by [summary operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/summary). Another way to think about this is to wrap the element you want to summary by summary op rather than record the element directly. This wrapping will create ["a Tensor containsing a Summary protobuf"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar), which is [the acceptable format of `add_summary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#add_summary).

In detail, you will create a summary op by:

```
loss_summ = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
```

Then run this op to get the tensor/value:

```
_, loss_value, loss_summ_val = sess.run((train, loss, loss_summ))
```

Finally, add the returned tensor/value rather then your actual `loss_value` to summary:

```
writer.add_summary(summary=loss_summ_val, global_step=i)
```

With minimum necessary changes, the following code will work. However, as "nairouz mrabah" suggested in the other answer, the structure of the code could be improved.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
WORKDIR = "/content/log"

x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)

y_pred = linear_model(x)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.name_scope("TRAIN"):
  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)
  loss_summ = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
  train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(WORKDIR + "/tmp/5", graph=sess.graph)

sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
  # _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
  _, loss_value, loss_summ_val = sess.run((train, loss, loss_summ))
  if i % 50 == 0:
    # writer.add_summary(summary=loss_value, global_step=i)
    writer.add_summary(summary=loss_summ_val, global_step=i)
    print(str(i)+" step: "+str(loss_value))
    writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

Comment: thanks, i think i have tried this too, but with the wrong order.
right now i think the solution was the combination of this answer and the previous one about the order. it works like charm

Comment: @ptamas90 Glad you make it work. I just updated my answer with a complete code for others coming to this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should fully create your graph (the loss and optimizer are part of the static graph), then you should create the session and finally, you can create a writer.
Keep the right order, then it will work.

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np
 WORKDIR = "/content/log"
 x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32)
 y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32)
 linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
 y_pred = linear_model(x)
 with tf.name_scope("TRAIN"):
 loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)
 optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
 train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
 with tf.Session() as sess:
      writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(WORKDIR + "/tmp/5", graph=sess.graph)
      sess.run(init)
      for i in range(1000):
         _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
         if i % 50 == 0:
         writer.add_summary(summary=loss_value, global_step=i)
         print(str(i)+" step: "+str(loss_value))
         writer.flush()
       writer.close()
```

Comment: i tried this way using the with statement for session creation right before the training cycle like you suggested, but it returns the same error as above :(

Comment: @ptamas90 Right order is the best and recommended practice though not required here. Nor it is the real cause of error here. Hope my answer below helps.